# Can I make up for missing skill opportunities?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have a sim who mastered gardening/cooking/fishing skills. According to [sims wiki](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Gardening_%28The_Sims_3%29), I should have get omni plant and some other plants via skill opportunities. Because my sim is filthy rich, I wasn't paying any attention to opportunities, because I thought they were just for extra money. However, I want to get Master Planter challange, and for that, I need to plant every possible plant. Can I somehow get this opportunities again? My sim is kind of immortal, so in game time is not problem.

Edit: I just realized I had something else filling up my skill opportunity slot. I removed it and waiting for the moment. But this question is still valid.

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry, the opportunity will come again, eventually. Missed opportunities are not lost forever, they do repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're not opposed to using hacks, I recommend Twallan's Master Controller mod, which gives you almost complete control over your game. There is an option to force a specific opportunity, so just select the opportunity you want and voila! 
There are a lot of options with this mod, but it is really very simple to use. Just be sure to keep your game up-to-date and you should be golden. Here is the site: http://nraas.wikispaces.com/